# No date part in '' found. Zend_Date->_calculate('set', false, NULL, 'en_US') in Magento

Tags: magento-1.7.0.1

I have a magento store. When I go to "**Sales > Shipment**" from admin. here all shipments are listed. When I clicked on "**View**" link of to see shipment info of any order, it gives an error. It is showed in error-

```
a:5:{i:0;s:25:"No date part in '' found.";i:1;s:5882:"#0 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\app\code\core\Zend\Date.php(1091): Zend_Date->_calculate('set', false, NULL, 'en_US')
#1 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\app\code\core\Zend\Date.php(210): Zend_Date->set(false, NULL, 'en_US')
#2 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Locale.php(516): Zend_Date->__construct(false, NULL, Object(Zend_Locale))
#3 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Abstract.php(82): Mage_Core_Model_Locale->storeDate(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Store), false, true)
#4 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\order\view\info.phtml(30): Mage_Sales_Model_Abstract->getCreatedAtStoreDate()
#5 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(241): include('E:\Php Projects...')
#6 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml\defau...')
#7 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#8 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#9 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(863): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#10 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#11 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('order_info', true)
#12 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\order\shipment\view\form.phtml(28): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('order_info')
#13 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(241): include('E:\Php Projects...')
#14 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml\defau...')
#15 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#16 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#17 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(863): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#18 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#19 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('form', true)
#20 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Form\Container.php(130): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('form')
#21 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\widget\form\container.phtml(37): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container->getFormHtml()
#22 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(241): include('E:\Php Projects...')
#23 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml\defau...')
#24 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#25 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#26 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Container.php(308): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#27 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(863): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container->_toHtml()
#28 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Text\List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#29 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#30 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#31 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#32 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\page.phtml(74): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#33 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(241): include('E:\Php Projects...')
#34 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml\defau...')
#35 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#36 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#37 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(863): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#38 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#39 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#40 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\Sales\Order\ShipmentController.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#41 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(419): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_ShipmentController->viewAction()
#42 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#43 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#44 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#45 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\app\Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#46 E:\Php Projects\BulkSms\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#47 {main}";s:3:"url";s:88:"/index.php/admin/sales_shipment/view/shipment_id/3/key/f26c45267fe7eefcea518b47f3bb1903/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

how can I remove this error.

Answer (score 1):

When you look at `lib\Zend\Locale\Format.php`

in

```
   private static function _parseDate($date, $options)
        {
..........
 // split number parts
    $split = false;
    preg_match_all('/\d+/u', $number, $splitted);

    if (count($splitted[0]) == 0) {
        iconv_set_encoding('internal_encoding', $oenc);
        #require_once 'Zend/Locale/Exception.php';
        throw new Zend_Locale_Exception("No date part in '$date' found."); // your error comes from here 

    }

}
```

I think After little bit debugging found that `pcre_match_all` function is failing to find any matches.

i think this `pcre_match_all` function is receiving `non-utf8` encoded text, and with the `/u` option the regular expression fails to parse the string correctly.

I would suggest just debug this code and try to find solution